# Lock analog in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, azure, azure-web-roles

I need to implement some thread consequent logic in Azure web instances. 
I have some code like this:

```
lock (_bookingLock)
{
    // Check for a free time
    bool isTimeFree = _scheduleService.IsTimeFree(dateTimeGuidId);
    //* race condition here
    if (isTimeFree)
    {
        // Make a booking. So this time is busy
        newBookingId = _paymentService.CreateBooking(dateTimeGuidId).ToString();
    }
}
```

But I can't use **`lock`** in a multi instance environment and I can't omit lock because there is a  race condition at `*`. What is the best approach here?

Comment: Are you working with a single entity? In other words, do you update the same entity by changing its attribute to booked if its available?

Comment: No, i have a table with free Time items. And i have a table with Bookings. I check if a time haven't bookings then this time is free and can be booked. But if two or more users simultaneously try to book free time then they will receive TWO bookings! In this case only one user must receive a booking and another users must receive a message that this time is busy.

Comment: Most databases have transactions or at least atomic check-and-update operations. Do a bit of research around "azure <YourDB> transaction"

Comment: I have Azure SQL DB. I read about table locking (whole table) in similar situations but this is very expensive operations. I wanna abstract from Data layer and sync my operations in Busyness layer.

Comment: [Transactions](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1639.handling-transactions-in-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx) are the way to go.

Comment: No, transactions it's not my choice because i can change database from Sql Azure to Azure Tables. I think about blob leases. How about this approach http://blog.smarx.com/posts/managing-concurrency-in-windows-azure-with-leases. If so i can modify my code like this: `bool opExecuted=false;
while(!opExecuted)
{
 using (var arl = new AutoRenewLease(blob))
    {
        if (arl.HasLease)
        {
            // Some Sync Work here
            //...
            
            opExecuted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}` is this good solution?

Comment: I'm confused :) ... are you using table storage or sql azure?

Comment: I use hybrid Database storage. And i just wanna know how to people solve my problems in Azure environment. Why i can't use blob leases like in my previous comment?

Comment: There are two ways of handling concurrency. Either pessimistic concurrency control which is what you are trying to do or optimistic concurrency control. Try optimistic, its probably easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to use blob leases. I upgraded [smarx's code](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/managing-concurrency-in-windows-azure-with-leases) to use Azure Storage client version 2 or 3 and wrote one addtitional method. Here is full code:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.Protocol;
using System.Configuration;

namespace TerminalManager.Domain.Foundation.BlobLeases
{
    public class AutoRenewLease : IDisposable
    {
        public bool HasLease { get { return leaseId != null; } }

        AccessCondition _accessCondition;
        private CloudBlockBlob blob;
        private string leaseId;
        private Thread renewalThread;
        private bool disposed = false;

        public static void DoOnce(CloudBlockBlob blob, Action action) { DoOnce(blob, action, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); }
        public static void DoOnce(CloudBlockBlob blob, Action action, TimeSpan pollingFrequency)
        {
            // blob.Exists has the side effect of calling blob.FetchAttributes, which populates the metadata collection
            while (!blob.Exists() || blob.Metadata["progress"] != "done")
            {
                using (var arl = new AutoRenewLease(blob))
                {
                    if (arl.HasLease)
                    {
                        action();
                        blob.Metadata["progress"] = "done";
                        AccessCondition ac = new AccessCondition();
                        ac.LeaseId = arl.leaseId;
                        blob.SetMetadata(ac);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(pollingFrequency);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Выполнить последовательно
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lockBlobName">имя блоба - просто буквы</param>
        /// <param name="action"></param>
        /// <param name="cnStrName">из конфига</param>
        /// <param name="containerName">из конфига</param>
        /// <param name="pollingFrequency"></param>
        public static void DoConsequence(string lockBlobName, Action action, 
            string cnStrName = "StorageConnectionString", 
            string containerName = "leasesContainer", TimeSpan? pollingFrequency = null)
        {
            //http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/

            // Формат пути к блобу
            //http://<storage account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/<blob>
            // Блобовский аккаунт
            var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[cnStrName].ConnectionString); //CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true"); // Не работает на SDK 2.2 // or your real connection string
            var blobs = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            // Контейнер - типа папки
            var container = blobs
                .GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[containerName]);
            container.CreateIfNotExists();

            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(lockBlobName);


            bool jobDone = false;

            while (!jobDone)
            {
                using (var arl = new AutoRenewLease(blob))
                {
                    if (arl.HasLease)
                    {
                        // Some Sync Work here 
                        action();
                        jobDone = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(pollingFrequency ?? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void DoEvery(CloudBlockBlob blob, TimeSpan interval, Action action)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var lastPerformed = DateTimeOffset.MinValue;
                using (var arl = new AutoRenewLease(blob))
                {
                    if (arl.HasLease)
                    {
                        blob.FetchAttributes();
                        DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(blob.Metadata["lastPerformed"], "R", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out lastPerformed);
                        if (DateTimeOffset.UtcNow >= lastPerformed + interval)
                        {
                            action();
                            lastPerformed = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
                            blob.Metadata["lastPerformed"] = lastPerformed.ToString("R");
                            AccessCondition ac = new AccessCondition();
                            ac.LeaseId = arl.leaseId;
                            blob.SetMetadata(ac);
                        }
                    }
                }
                var timeLeft = (lastPerformed + interval) - DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
                var minimum = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5); // so we're not polling the leased blob too fast
                Thread.Sleep(
                    timeLeft > minimum
                    ? timeLeft
                    : minimum);
            }
        }

        public AutoRenewLease(CloudBlockBlob blob)
        {
            this.blob = blob;
            blob.Container.CreateIfNotExists();
            try
            {
                if (!blob.Exists())
                {
                    blob.UploadFromByteArray(new byte[0], 0, 0, AccessCondition.GenerateIfNoneMatchCondition("*"));// new BlobRequestOptions { AccessCondition = AccessCondition.IfNoneMatch("*") });
                }
            }
            catch (StorageException e)
            {
                if (e.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode != (int)HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed // 412 from trying to modify a blob that's leased
                    && e.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorCode != BlobErrorCodeStrings.BlobAlreadyExists
                    )
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            try
            {
                leaseId = blob.AcquireLease(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), null);
                _accessCondition = new AccessCondition { LeaseId = leaseId };
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("==========> Lease rejected! <==========");
            }

            if (HasLease)
            {
                renewalThread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
                        var ac = new AccessCondition();
                        ac.LeaseId = leaseId;
                        blob.RenewLease(ac);//.RenewLease(leaseId);
                    }
                });
                renewalThread.Start();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if (renewalThread != null)
                    {
                        renewalThread.Abort();
                        blob.ReleaseLease(_accessCondition);
                        renewalThread = null;
                    }
                }
                disposed = true;
            }
        }

        ~AutoRenewLease()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how to use this (don't forget about setup config for blob connection string and catalog name):

```
// lock analog
    AutoRenewLease.DoConsequence("testBlob2", () =>
                            {
// Some task
                                if (collection == 0)
                                {
                                    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 2);
                                    collection++;
                                }
                                Trace.WriteLine(tNo + " =====Collection=" + collection);
                                Trace.WriteLine(tNo + " =====MustBe = 1");
                            });
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work. All this actually does is guarantee leased access to the blob. For broader issues read this: https://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/02/08/how-to-do-distributed-locking.html

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend modeling this through a series of messages.  You can send a message (command) via Azure Service Bus to create booking.  Only one consumer will process the message and you won't need a "lock".  In addition, you can scale out to multiple consumers so that you can process multiple commands concurrently.  Events can also be used to notify consumers of changes in state (like a booking was created or updated) and do what they need to do.

Comment: Not really. Correctness comes at a cost. It's also why Service Bus queues with "at most once" delivery guarantees exist.